# How to append to a specific tag if it has an attribute that contains specific word using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am fairly new XSLT and this is my xml :

```
<a>
      <b>
                <f>
                          <g>ok</g>
                          <h>ok</h>
                </f>
                <b test="word1">
                          <d>ok1</d>
                          <e test="1">ok11</e>
                </b>
                <b test="word2">
                          <d>ok2</d>
                          <e test="1">ok22</e>
                </b>
                <b test="word3">
                          <d>ok3</d>
                          <e test="1">ok33</e>
                </b>
                <b test="word4">
                          <d>ok4</d>
                          <e test="1">ok44</e>
                </b>
      </b>
```

I need my output to look something like this :

```
<a>
      <b>
                <f>
                          <g>ok</g>
                          <h>ok</h>
                </f>
                <b test="word">
                          <d>ok1</d>
                          <e test="1">ok11</e>

                          <d>ok2</d>
                          <e test="1">ok22</e>

                          <d>ok3</d>
                          <e test="1">ok33</e>

                          <d>ok4</d>
                          <e test="1">ok44</e>
                </b >
      </b>
```

I need to append 'b' tag , if it has an attribute that contains 'word'.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you want to merge adjacent `b` elements if the `test` attribute value contains the substring `word`? Which version of XSLT can you use? For XSLT 2.0 and later you could use `xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="contains(@test, 'word')"`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen , I don't mind using xslt 2.0! okay I will try once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**XSLT-1.0 solution:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">                                 <!-- identity template - generally copying all nodes -->
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="b[contains(@test,'word')][1]">              <!-- copy first b node and following b node's content -->
  <b test="word">
    <xsl:copy-of select="../b[contains(@test,'word')]/*" />
  </b>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="b[contains(@test,'word')]" priority="0" />  <!-- remove following b nodes -->

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output:**

```
<a>
    <b>
        <f>
            <g>ok</g>
            <h>ok</h>
        </f>
        <b test="word">
            <d>ok1</d>
            <e test="1">ok11</e>
            <d>ok2</d>
            <e test="1">ok22</e>
            <d>ok3</d>
            <e test="1">ok33</e>
            <d>ok4</d>
            <e test="1">ok44</e>
        </b>
    </b>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using XSLT 2.0/3.0 you can use `xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="boolean(self::b[contains(@test, $str)])"`

here is an XSLT 3.0 stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:param name="str" as="xs:string" select="'word'"/>

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:template match="*[b[contains(@test, $str)]]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="boolean(self::b[contains(@test, $str)])">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                        <b test="{$str}">
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()/node()"/>
                        </b>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With XSLT 2.0 remove the `xsl:mode` and spell out the identity transformation template

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

instead.